# LogCat filtering

Tags: android, filter, logcat, ddms

Is there a way to quickly filter the logs by PID?
I'm tired of typing in the filter name and PID manually each time.
It seem so straightforward and logical to right-click the message and choose "Filter by id" from the context menu, but LogCat has nothing similar :\ Or has it? Any LogCat alternatives out there?

Comment: What you mention is exactly how LogRabbit filters message. Right click on PID or AppName and save filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, take it easy, you just need to input `Filter Name` and `Log Tag` being the same text and leave empty the `PID`. That's enough buddy :)

Sample, I want to filter all tag `MyApp`, then just create new filter with

```
Filter Name: MyApp (or whatever)
Log Tag: MyApp (must be exactly)
PID: (leave empty, input nothing)
Type: pick one of the list that suits
```

:)

Comment: Ha-ha, well, it may seem like there's much ado about nothing, and maybe it is, but when you run the app next time it no longer has the same PID, so you have to repeat the procedure all over again.
I tried entering app name for the filter and tag, but this didn't work. Could you explain what you meant by "MyApp"?

Comment: `Filter Name` which is to display in LogCat tab, you can name it whatever you like, I always name it the same as the `Log Tag` for easy recognition. I never use `PID`, just `Log Tag` is enough for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. Granted, seeing "System.out" messages is enough for me.

Comment: You're not supposed to output `System.out` on final release application, it's fine for debug mode :).